# Which countries can publish paid apps in app store (apple)?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have question about where I can find list of countries which can publish paid apps on app store?

Answer (score 0):

Go to MY Apps and go to pricing and Availability section.

[image]
[image]

Here you can choose.

Comment: I need to know developers from which countries can sell their app in appstore. The one you posted is for choosing countries that I want to sell my app. But for selling there should be requirement that developer from those countries only can put paid apps.

Comment: @NatigBabayev did you find the list of the countries?